# Convert Java Objects to Json in BlackBerry

Tags: json, blackberry, java-me

I am working on converting a java bean object to json object. Is there any library available for BlackBerry, similar to the libraries available for Java on Android, that can do the conversion automatically?  The Android libraries don't work on BlackBerry.

Answer (score 5):

For OS 6.0 and later JSON ME is included in the API. Check the package `org.json.me`. For OS 5.0 and smaller, you have to use a third party library. You can download JSON ME from here:

https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/

Comment: it does not have any method to convert java objects to json or otherwise

Comment: With this library, you should do the serialization manually. I don't know of any other library compatible with JavaME that is able to do this automatically (probably due to the lack of Reflection in JavaME).